# Better way to create directories using File

Tags: java, file-system, directory

I have this code that generally creates directories within a directory.

```
File  userFolder = new File(rootPath+"/media/"+userBean.getUsername());
    File  userPhotosDir = new File(rootPath+"/media/"+userBean.getUsername()+"/photos");
    File  userAudioDir = new File(rootPath+"/media/"+userBean.getUsername()+"/tracks");
    userFolder.mkdir();
    userPhotosDir.mkdir();
    userAudioDir.mkdir();
```

When I this code runs it will generally look like this

The userFolder

```
\media\somename
```

The Photos folder

```
\media\somename\photos
```

The Audio Folder

```
\media\somename\folder
```

Where the photos and audio folder are inside the somename folder. while the somename folder is inside the media folder

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

Well, for the purpose of codereview:

- There is a `mkdirs()` methods instead of the `mkdir()` method
- You can use the `new File(String, String)` constructor to avoid taking care of slashes
- If you have Java7, you can (and probably should) use `Path`. Especially, because there is a way to construct Paths with unlimited arguments, not only 2 as for `File`:

  ```
  Path dir = Paths.get(rootPath, "media", userBean.getUsername(), arg1);
  Files.createDirectories(dir);
  ```
- You should check the return codes and errors. Could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

My main concern would be dealing with file path separators to construct long file paths. Luckily Java has `File.separator` which can be used to to manually construct paths. However try not to use them if necessary, and get the File objects to do the path creation for you.

```
String rootPath = "/";
String username = "tom";
String mediaDir = "media"
File root = new File(rootPath);
File userFolder = new File(root, mediaDir + File.separator + username);
File photos = new File(userFolder, "photos");
File tracks = new File(userFolder, "tracks");
if (photos.isFile()) {
    // delete it? Do something...
}
if (!photos.exists()) {
    photos.mkdirs();
}
```

Like tb- suggests in his answer, if you have Java 7 you may also want to look into [Paths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html), [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) and [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)